# Default button highlighting in Flash similar to iOS UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript-3, flash

iOS has a default UIButton highlighting mechanism that really cuts down the preliminary design work needed to come up with a prototype. Does Flash have something similar?

**Note that I'm not asking this for use on iOS, the question is for Flash apps that are going to be run on the web**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not possible in flash by default. If you want to create a highlighted effect SimpleButton or MovieClip, you must create effect. using a MotionScript or Actionscripts effects must be implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I would appreciate pointers if you have some in mind :)